# Why is the Post route not accepting the variable value(using express)?

Tags: express, web, server, routes, ejs

This is my app.js file here I'm creating two simple Get and Post request

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

var todos = ["Water Plants", "Feed Zorro", "Buy Groceries", "Read Books"];

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/:name/todo", function(req, res){
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render("home", {name : name, todos : todos});
});

app.post("/:name/todo", function(req, res){
    var name = req.params.name;
    var newTodo = req.body.newTodo;
    todos.push(newTodo);
    res.redirect("/:name/todo");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This is my home.ejs file

```
<% include partials/header %>
<h1>Welcome <%= name %></h1>
<% for(var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){ %>
    <li><%= todos[i] %></li>
<% } %>
<form action="/:name/todo" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="newTodo" placeholder="Add Todo..."><br>
    <button>Add Todo</button>
</form>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

Whenever I go to localhost:3000/Jazz/todo the html header shows "Welcome Jazz" but when I try to make a post request by adding an item to the list, the header then turns to "Welcome :name" but it should be the same "Welcome Jazz". What is causing this abnormal error and what is the solution?
Packages I am using are express, ejs, body-parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make correction in route. You need to present compiled name there

```
<form action="/<%= name %>/todo" method="POST">
```

And submit request via ajax. As page refresh after post request, it does not get data back to display. Therefore you are getting an error

Comment: With the correction you provided it gave the same result, in addition to your correction I changed the post redirect line a bit to `res.redirect("/" + name +"/todo");`  and it worked. And I will start with AJAX soon. And thanks @mabc224